# Invoking struct default destructor?

Tags: c++, struct, destructor

In C++, since you can have class-instances as members in structs, the compiler has an implicit destructor just like classes to clean them up. I can invoke a destructor of a class when I allocate an object into my own memory with the fixed-memory new-operator and need to clean it up, but what if I allocate a struct the same way? I know one workaround is to call the destructor of each class instance in the struct, just wondering if there was a way.

Comment: `class` and `struct` behave essentially the same. The only difference is the default access type: `private` in `class`, and `public` is `struct`

Comment: Yeah, total nvm. I should already know this, too much C# does this to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same rules that apply to classes also apply to structs. The only difference between `class` and `struct` is the default access level, and no other.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right. You can define a destructor just like a class to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference; `class` and `struct` are essentially identical:

```
class Bar { /* .. */ };

struct Foo
{
    Bar x;
};

char arena[HUGE];

Foo * p = ::new (arena) Foo;  // construct
p->~Foo();                    // destroy; calls the destructor for p->x as expected
```